# High school mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, energy-conservation, work

Is it possible for Kinetic energy to be constant in conservative or non conservative systems. Yes constant velocity will result in constant Kinetic energy. But what if it is a non conservative system. Is it necessary for Kinetic energy to change? What if only potential energy changes ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible (or at least, one can get really close to it). For example, if you drop something, for example a ball, out of a very high place, it will not be on free fall due to the presence of the atmosphere. The effects of air resistance will eventually lead to the ball reaching [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity), meaning that from this point onwards its velocity is kept constant (the air resistance perfectly matches the gravitational force, and hence there is vanishing net force), despite the fact that the gravitational potential energy is getting smaller.

To address the parentheses in the beginning of my question: terminal velocity is actually achieved asymptotically (meaning you get really really close, but never quite there), so there is a caveat in my answer.

Comment: It is also possible for the ball to start on the ground. Nothing moves, so kinetic energy is always $0$. Or for the initial velocity to be exactly terminal velocity.